# Get the number of triads

Tags: r, geometry, igraph

Consider the following undirected network:

```
1   2
2   3
3   4
4   2
5   7
5   6
6   7
7   6
10  1
10  2
```

How can I count the number of triads in this network?
Using `triad.census` [(link)](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/igraph/docs/triad.census) I get:

```
[1]  1.500000e+01  3.700000e+01  0.000000e+00 6.944418e-310  4.000000e+00 2.371515e-322 1.506900e-321 3.913638e-315 2.916720e-316
[10] 2.781342e-309 3.162020e-322 5.010211e-316 8.344027e-309 6.944406e-310 6.944406e-310 1.251613e-308
Warning message:
In .Call("R_igraph_triad_census", graph, PACKAGE = "igraph") :
  At motifs.c:1050 :Triad census called on an undirected graph
```

I assume, there are 3 triads.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `triad.census` for an undirected graph. As in the link you gave

> Arguments
>   graph
>   The input graph, it should be directed. An undirected graph results a warning, and undefined results.

Here is one way:

```
 library(statnet)
 library(ergm)
 library(sna)
 data(faux.magnolia.high)
 fmh <- faux.magnolia.high
 summary(fmh ~ triangle)
#triangle 
#    169
```

or alternatively make your graph explicitly directed and then you will get the number of different types of triads from `triad.census`

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to count *triangles*, not triads. This can be done either with `graph.count.subisomorphisms.vf2` which you can use to search for an arbitrary graph "template" and count the occurrences, or you can use `graph.motifs` to count the number of each possible subgraphs of size 3 and then take the component of the result that represents triangles:

```
> g <- graph(c(1,2,2,3,3,1,3,4,4,5,5,3), directed=F)
> graph.motifs(g, size=3)
[1] NA NA  4  2
```

This tells you that you have 2 triangles in the example graph.

```
> triangle <- graph.full(3)
> graph.count.subisomorphisms.vf2(g, triangle) / 6
[1] 2
```

The result of `graph.count.subisomorphisms.vf2` has to be divided by 6 because there are six possible ways to map a triangle to itself (by permuting the vertices), hence each triangle will be counted six times by `graph.count.subisomorphisms.vf2`. (`graph.motifs` accounts for this already).

Comment: This is good, but it is actually faster to use `adjacent.triangles`, and then divide the sum by three. The development version of igraph also has a function to count the triangles, if I remember well.

Comment: I actually need the number of the triads. Using `graph.motifs.no(g,size=3)` I get as a result 7, with `adjacent.triangles(g)/3` I get 3. What would be the right result in my case? I assume 3 is right.